# jQuery selector for elements with attribute starting with string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select all elements, which have an attribute starting with a given prefix - note I am talking about the attribute name, *not* value.  For example:

```
<div data-abc-name="value">...</div>
<a href="..." data-abc-another="something">...</a>
<span data-nonabc="123">...</span>
```

In the above HTML, I need to get all elements that have an attribute starting with `data-abc-` - that is, the `div` and the `a`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solutions - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvx9eyxg/). You have to create your own jquery selector.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    attrStartsWith: function (el, _, b) {
        for (var i = 0, atts = el.attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++) {
            if(atts[i].nodeName.toLowerCase().indexOf(b[3].toLowerCase()) === 0) {
                return true; 
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
});

//e.g:
$('a:attrStartsWith("data-abc")').html('hello');
$('div:attrStartsWith("data-abc")').html('hello');
```

Comment: I had to use this recently. I found the answer here somewhere, but I couldn't find the source just now. If someone knows, let me know and I'll provide author the ownership!

Comment: This actually looks promising.  So, to find all such elements, I'd use `$('*:attrStartsWith("data-abc-")')`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this by ES6:

```
$('*').filter(function() {
  for (attr of this.attributes)
    if (attr.name.startsWith("data-abc"))
      return this;
});
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/7u35czog/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.from(document.querySelector('element').attributes).filter(x=>x.name.startsWith('attr-starts-with'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have `jQuery` selector with `regex`. However you can make use of [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/)

Until you find a proper selector, here is a small workaround, that selects elements with matching `attribute`

```js
var nodes = [];
$("body > *").each(function(){ //iterating over all nodes
  $(this.attributes).each(function(){
    console.log(this.nodeName);
    if(this.nodeName.indexOf("data-abc") > -1){
      nodes.push(this);
    }
  });
});

console.log(nodes.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-abc-name="value">...</div>
<a href="..." data-abc-another="something">...</a>
<span data-nonabc="123">...</span>
```

Comment: Yeah, if no selector is available, manually traversing the DOM and checking attributes is the only option.  However this is extremely inefficient.  Your code only checks top level elements.  I need to find elements everywhere in the DOM.  And the DOM itself is very large in my case (over a million elements).  That said, mostly likely, that's why jQuery is doing anyway.